# Mountain Lion 10.8.3 file sharing broken for particular named folder

Tags: macos, sharing, afp

I'm running Mountain Lion 10.8.3 on a 2012 Mac Mini. The Mini is headless and I'm using an iMac to do screen sharing for admin purposes. I'm trying to set up sharing of a particular folder on an external HDD attached to the Mini via USB3, but for some reason I can't share this folder and the problem seems to be related to its name. I would like to know what I can do (other than just renaming the folder) to fix the problem.

In more detail: I'm trying to share a folder containing FLAC music files. These files are in a folder called *Music/FLAC* on the volume *Titan*, an external HDD attached to the Mini (*Saturn*). Hence I'm trying to share the folder *FLAC*.

The HDD has been formatted as Mac OS Extended (Journaled). I don't know how to work out whether it is case sensitive or not. In Disk Utility I can run Verify Disk and it says the volume appears to be okay but Verify Disk Permissions is greyed out (because owners are not enabled for external drives?).

I'm logged in using an administrator account. I go to *Sharing* in System Preferences. The *File Sharing* service is checked. In *Options*, *Share files and folders using AFP* is checked; SMB is not. I click the + button to add a share, navigate to the FLAC folder, and click *Add*. The dialog closes, but no share is added. Similarly, if I navigate to the folder using Finder, do *Get Info* then check the *Shared folder* checkbox, the change is not persisted when I close the *Get Info* dialog.

If I look in the Console app, I see entries like this:

> System Preferences[4648]: SFL(4648): AddNewItemWithProperties_rpc
>   returned -36 System Preferences[4648]: LSSharedFileListInsertItemFSRef
>   returned NULL for path:/Volumes/Titan/Music/FLAC

Now here's the really odd part. If I rename the folder to *flac* (that is, change the case), then the file sharing works fine! Some experimentation with various casing seems to suggest that all lowercase is fine, but **any** uppercase letter causes the share to fail. The computer is happy to share the *MP3* folder located in the *Music* folder however.

I'm kind of at a loss to explain this behaviour, but then I don't have much experience with Macs.

The only other thing that may have a bearing on this (although I hope not) is that there is also a NAS box on the same Ethernet network that has a public SMB share named *flac*. I can't see how this would make any difference though.

### Update 26 March

@GrahamPerrin: Your steps 1-4 are basically what I had already done, but I tried again to make sure. No change: *flac* works ok, *FLAC* doesn't.

As a quick fix, I was going to share the folder as *flac*, but although it shared, the share appeared as *flac-1* on the iMac. Whatever is going on it definitely doesn't like that folder name, regardless of casing. So now I've renamed the folder to *FLACs* and shared it like that, and it seems happy enough.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what to tell you about the actual problem but I can share some insight that might help you track it down.  The iMac connecting to the lower case "flac" share but mounting it as "flac-1" tells me it's all ready connected to a volume named some form of flac.  It could just be that it's all ready connected to the SMB NAS you mentioned.

Regardless I've seen an issue where software expects a certain path and instead of throwing an error about not finding the path it just tried to create it which then leaves a sort of null path that you have to manually remove.  If you don't remove it then names like "flac-1" start appearing.  Re-reading that it may not make sense but regardless the steps I've used to see what's what are firing up Terminal (found in /Applications/Utilities) and typing:

```
ls -la /Volumes
```

If you see more listed here than you expect or can find through normal finder navigation then you can remove them (Only do this if you're 100% sure it's a path that contains nothing you ever want to see again!) by typing:

```
rm -rf /Volumes/NULLPATH
```

where NULLPATH is what you wan to get rid of.

Along these lines if the mini is all ready showing a "FLAC" or some such in /Volumes then you're not goign to be able to share a folder by the same name.  As in if the mini is connected to the SMB NAS then you're going to have to use a different share name.

Also you can turn ownership on, on your external HD by opening the get info window on the drive and checking the box at the bottom of the window to "Enable Ownership on this volume".  I'm not sue it will in any way effect your issue but might be something to try.

Comment: I tried "ls -la /Volumes" and didn't see anything I wasn't expecting, although it did say there were eight volumes but only listed five of them. How would I view the other three?

Answer (score 0):

## -36

On OS X, -36 is an I/O error (historically [a bummer](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT1618)).

Is the file system of the external disk HFS Plus? Case insensitive or sensitive?

Begin with a verification of file system integrity.

### A change from the working configuration

> … rename the folder to flac (that is, change the case), then the file sharing works …

Try:

1. make file sharing work with *flac*
2. from the Sharing pane of System Preferences, remove that folder
3. rename from *flac* to *FLAC*
4. add FLAC to the list of shared folders.

Specifically:

- do **not** change the name of a folder whilst it is shared.

### LSSharedFileListInsertItemFSRef returned NULL for path:

This string appears in Apple Support Communities: [Oh boy, what did 10.6.2 do to my iMac  file sharing?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2232253) … the question there is unanswered and whilst we can't reply, I do recognise the user from elsewhere. I might be able to contact him in a few weeks.

Comment: Thanks @SteveRands, and a hint: you can/should edit your opening question to include the additional information; then you can remove all three comments.

Comment: I've edited the question with further info. Sorry I can't accept your answer as it didn't fix the problem; I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep yet.